# spinlocks & jiffy updation

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel32

I have couple of questions.
1) In case of UP how is jiffies(timer) get updated while holding spin lock using spinlock_irq_save?
2)My understanding is in smp environment jiffies updation cannot be done on processor holding spinlock irrespective of spinlock API.So timer interrupt should be enabled across all cores in SoC. Imagine a scenario in quad core processor where 4 cores are holding 4 different spinlocks & how is the timer interrupt for jiffies handled?

Any help here will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. simple - it isn't. 2. spin lock and other critical section that disable IRQs must be very short. Jiffie updates only occurs when IRQs are enabled.

Comment: So spin_lock cannot be held for a period of jiffy? & if spinlock is acquired just before PIT triggers interrupt, that jiffy is lost?

Comment: If you are holding a spin lock for long duration, most certainly as something as long as a jiffie you are doing something wrong. period.

No, jiffies are not lost. The PIT timer interrupt is latched. You'll get your interrupt once you unlock the spin lock